# how to change tab color in android view pager with tab Strip

Tags: android, layout

This is my Xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" >

                <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="#d3d3d3"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my main actvity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {   
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(new                   ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }
    }
```

this is my viewpageAdapter class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 10;
    // Tab Titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Tables", "Water", "Fan"};
Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TableFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new WaterFragment();

        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new FancoolerFragment();

}

        return null;
}
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Screen1 is my cureent Screen : Screen2 :Desire Screen  please help me how to acchive this i am unable to set text and background color of tab when Particular tab is enabled or open please suggest me how to get this

Comment: PagerTabStrip has property android:textColor set your color here and it will effect to Tab also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, I think it is not possible with default PagerTabStrip.

Try any of the two solutions for your design,

1. Use buttons as tabs for viewpager
2. Use **Custom PagerTitleStrip**

   public class PagerSlidingTabStrip extends HorizontalScrollView {

   ```
   public interface IconTabProvider {
       public int getPageIconResId(int position);
   }

   // @formatter:off
   private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
           android.R.attr.textSize,
           android.R.attr.textColor
   };
   // @formatter:on

   private LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultTabLayoutParams;
   private LinearLayout.LayoutParams expandedTabLayoutParams;

   private final PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
   public OnPageChangeListener delegatePageListener;

   private LinearLayout tabsContainer;
   private ViewPager pager;

   private int tabCount;

   private int currentPosition = 0;
   private float currentPositionOffset = 0f;

   private Paint rectPaint;
   private Paint dividerPaint;

   private int indicatorColor = 0xEEFFFFFF;
   private int underlineColor = 0x33FFFFFF;
   private int dividerColor = 0x00FFFFFF;

   private boolean shouldExpand = false;
   private boolean textAllCaps = true;

   private int scrollOffset = 52;
   private int indicatorHeight = 4;
   private int underlineHeight = 2;
   private int dividerPadding = 0;
   private int tabPadding = 0;
   private int dividerWidth = 0;

   private int tabTextSize = 14;
   private int tabTextColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   private Typeface tabTypeface = null;
   private int tabTypefaceStyle = Typeface.NORMAL;

   private int lastScrollX = 0;

   private int tabBackgroundResId = R.drawable.background_media_pager_tab;

   private Locale locale;

   public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
       this(context, null);
   }

   public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       this(context, attrs, 0);
   }

   public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);

       setFillViewport(true);
       setWillNotDraw(false);

       tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
       tabsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
       tabsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
       addView(tabsContainer);

       DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

       scrollOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, scrollOffset, dm);
       indicatorHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, indicatorHeight, dm);
       underlineHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, underlineHeight, dm);
       dividerPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerPadding, dm);
       tabPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, tabPadding, dm);
       dividerWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerWidth, dm);
       tabTextSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, tabTextSize, dm);

       // get system attrs (android:textSize and android:textColor)

       TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS);

       tabTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, tabTextSize);
       tabTextColor = a.getColor(1, tabTextColor);

       a.recycle();

       // get custom attrs

       a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip);

       indicatorColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorColor, indicatorColor);
       underlineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineColor, underlineColor);
       dividerColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerColor, dividerColor);
       indicatorHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorHeight, indicatorHeight);
       underlineHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineHeight, underlineHeight);
       dividerPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerPadding, dividerPadding);
       tabPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabPaddingLeftRight, tabPadding);
       tabBackgroundResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabBackground, tabBackgroundResId);
       shouldExpand = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsShouldExpand, shouldExpand);
       scrollOffset = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsScrollOffset, scrollOffset);
       textAllCaps = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTextAllCaps, textAllCaps);

       a.recycle();

       rectPaint = new Paint();
       rectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
       rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

       dividerPaint = new Paint();
       dividerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
       dividerPaint.setStrokeWidth(dividerWidth);

       defaultTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
       expandedTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

       if (locale == null) {
           locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
       }
   }

   public void setViewPager(ViewPager pager) {
       this.pager = pager;

       if (pager.getAdapter() == null) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
       }

       pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
       this.delegatePageListener = listener;
   }

   public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

       tabsContainer.removeAllViews();

       tabCount = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

       for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

           if (pager.getAdapter() instanceof IconTabProvider) {
               addIconTab(i, ((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(i));
           } else {
               addTextTab(i, pager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(i).toString());
           }

       }

       updateTabStyles();

       getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           @SuppressLint("NewApi")
           @Override
           public void onGlobalLayout() {

               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                   getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
               } else {
                   getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
               }

               currentPosition = pager.getCurrentItem();
               scrollToChild(currentPosition, 0);
           }
       });

   }

   private void addTextTab(final int position, String title) {

       TextView tab = new TextView(getContext());
       tab.setText(title);
       tab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
       tab.setSingleLine();

       addTab(position, tab);
   }

   private void addIconTab(final int position, int resId) {

       ImageButton tab = new ImageButton(getContext());
       tab.setImageResource(resId);

       addTab(position, tab);

   }

   private void addTab(final int position, View tab) {
       tab.setFocusable(true);
       tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               pager.setCurrentItem(position);
           }
       });

       tab.setPadding(tabPadding, 0, tabPadding, 0);
       tabsContainer.addView(tab, position, shouldExpand ? expandedTabLayoutParams : defaultTabLayoutParams);
   }

   private void updateTabStyles() {

       for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

           View v = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);

           v.setBackgroundResource(tabBackgroundResId);

           if (v instanceof TextView) {

               TextView tab = (TextView) v;
               tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, tabTextSize);
               tab.setTypeface(tabTypeface, tabTypefaceStyle);
               tab.setTextColor(tabTextColor);

               // setAllCaps() is only available from API 14, so the upper case is made manually if we are on a
               // pre-ICS-build
               if (textAllCaps) {
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                       tab.setAllCaps(true);
                   } else {
                       tab.setText(tab.getText().toString().toUpperCase(locale));
                   }
               }
           }
       }

   }

   private void scrollToChild(int position, int offset) {

       if (tabCount == 0) {
           return;
       }

       int newScrollX = tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getLeft() + offset;

       if (position > 0 || offset > 0) {
           newScrollX -= scrollOffset;
       }

       if (newScrollX != lastScrollX) {
           lastScrollX = newScrollX;
           scrollTo(newScrollX, 0);
       }

   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);

       if (isInEditMode() || tabCount == 0) {
           return;
       }

       final int height = getHeight();

       // draw indicator line

       rectPaint.setColor(indicatorColor);

       // default: line below current tab
       View currentTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition);
       float lineLeft = currentTab.getLeft();
       float lineRight = currentTab.getRight();

       // if there is an offset, start interpolating left and right coordinates between current and next tab
       if (currentPositionOffset > 0f && currentPosition < tabCount - 1) {

           View nextTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition + 1);
           final float nextTabLeft = nextTab.getLeft();
           final float nextTabRight = nextTab.getRight();

           lineLeft = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabLeft + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineLeft);
           lineRight = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabRight + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineRight);
       }

       canvas.drawRect(lineLeft, height - indicatorHeight, lineRight, height, rectPaint);

       // draw underline

       rectPaint.setColor(underlineColor);
       canvas.drawRect(0, height - underlineHeight, tabsContainer.getWidth(), height, rectPaint);

       // draw divider

       dividerPaint.setColor(dividerColor);
       for (int i = 0; i < tabCount - 1; i++) {
           View tab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);
           canvas.drawLine(tab.getRight(), dividerPadding, tab.getRight(), height - dividerPadding, dividerPaint);
       }
   }

   private class PageListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

           currentPosition = position;
           currentPositionOffset = positionOffset;

           scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset * tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getWidth()));

           invalidate();

           if (delegatePageListener != null) {
               delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
           if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
               scrollToChild(pager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
           }

           if (delegatePageListener != null) {
               delegatePageListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           if (delegatePageListener != null) {
               delegatePageListener.onPageSelected(position);
           }
       }

   }

   public void setIndicatorColor(int indicatorColor) {
       this.indicatorColor = indicatorColor;
       invalidate();
   }

   public void setIndicatorColorResource(int resId) {
       this.indicatorColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
       invalidate();
   }

   public int getIndicatorColor() {
       return this.indicatorColor;
   }

   public void setIndicatorHeight(int indicatorLineHeightPx) {
       this.indicatorHeight = indicatorLineHeightPx;
       invalidate();
   }

   public int getIndicatorHeight() {
       return indicatorHeight;
   }

   public void setUnderlineColor(int underlineColor) {
       this.underlineColor = underlineColor;
       invalidate();
   }

   public void setUnderlineColorResource(int resId) {
       this.underlineColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
       invalidate();
   }

   public int getUnderlineColor() {
       return underlineColor;
   }

   public void setDividerColor(int dividerColor) {
       this.dividerColor = dividerColor;
       invalidate();
   }

   public void setDividerColorResource(int resId) {
       this.dividerColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
       invalidate();
   }

   public int getDividerColor() {
       return dividerColor;
   }

   public void setUnderlineHeight(int underlineHeightPx) {
       this.underlineHeight = underlineHeightPx;
       invalidate();
   }

   public int getUnderlineHeight() {
       return underlineHeight;
   }

   public void setDividerPadding(int dividerPaddingPx) {
       this.dividerPadding = dividerPaddingPx;
       invalidate();
   }

   public int getDividerPadding() {
       return dividerPadding;
   }

   public void setScrollOffset(int scrollOffsetPx) {
       this.scrollOffset = scrollOffsetPx;
       invalidate();
   }

   public int getScrollOffset() {
       return scrollOffset;
   }

   public void setShouldExpand(boolean shouldExpand) {
       this.shouldExpand = shouldExpand;
       requestLayout();
   }

   public boolean getShouldExpand() {
       return shouldExpand;
   }

   public boolean isTextAllCaps() {
       return textAllCaps;
   }

   public void setAllCaps(boolean textAllCaps) {
       this.textAllCaps = textAllCaps;
   }

   public void setTextSize(int textSizePx) {
       this.tabTextSize = textSizePx;
       updateTabStyles();
   }

   public int getTextSize() {
       return tabTextSize;
   }

   public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
       this.tabTextColor = textColor;
       updateTabStyles();
   }

   public void setTextColorResource(int resId) {
       this.tabTextColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
       updateTabStyles();
   }

   public int getTextColor() {
       return tabTextColor;
   }

   public void setTypeface(Typeface typeface, int style) {
       this.tabTypeface = typeface;
       this.tabTypefaceStyle = style;
       updateTabStyles();
   }

   public void setTabBackground(int resId) {
       this.tabBackgroundResId = resId;
   }

   public int getTabBackground() {
       return tabBackgroundResId;
   }

   public void setTabPaddingLeftRight(int paddingPx) {
       this.tabPadding = paddingPx;
       updateTabStyles();
   }

   public int getTabPaddingLeftRight() {
       return tabPadding;
   }

   @Override
   public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
       SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
       super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
       currentPosition = savedState.currentPosition;
       requestLayout();
   }

   @Override
   public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
       Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
       SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
       savedState.currentPosition = currentPosition;
       return savedState;
   }

   static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
       int currentPosition;

       public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
           super(superState);
       }

       private SavedState(Parcel in) {
           super(in);
           currentPosition = in.readInt();
       }

       @Override
       public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
           super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
           dest.writeInt(currentPosition);
       }

       public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Creator<SavedState>() {
           @Override
           public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
               return new SavedState(in);
           }

           @Override
           public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
               return new SavedState[size];
           }
       };
   }
   ```

   }

In your layout.xml

```
<com.xxx.yyy.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

In your activity,

```
    PagerSlidingTabStrip mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_strip);

            mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setShouldExpand(true);
 mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
            mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Create attrs.xml in your values folder and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="PagerSlidingTabStrip">
        <attr name="pstsIndicatorColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="pstsUnderlineColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="pstsDividerColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="pstsIndicatorHeight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsUnderlineHeight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsDividerPadding" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsTabPaddingLeftRight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsScrollOffset" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsTabBackground" format="reference" />
        <attr name="pstsShouldExpand" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="pstsTextAllCaps" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Comment: but how to call  this so that i can apply with in my project  @Zahid

Comment: a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
   R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip);
  
   indicatorColor =
   a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorColor,
   indicatorColor);  am getting Error in this Line showing PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot be resolved or is not a field  please tellme how to fix it

Comment: Create respective attr elements... check my editted answer

Comment: now how i will call i have my XMl and my actvity class coz when i try to set it i am getting Error please suggest me @Zahid

Comment: Hey.. Did u resolve the issue.. Seems you didn't give the correct path of your class in xml

Comment: thanx its done one more need help please help me  error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix  i m getting this error

Comment: how to set Divider i am unable to set divider in this example please tell me

Answer (score 2):

Their is alternative you can use

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bb455a64"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#aaffff64"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@layout/drawer_row"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFF" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think main solution, it's custom buttons with ViewPager. Just create custom buttons, which switch color if click. And add ViewPager, which change current buttons. Thats all..

Comment: how to add custom button please help me